# asp-validation-summary not showing, field validation working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Im using dotnet core MVC and am having issues with asp-validation-summary.

Validation is working at a field level using asp-validation-for however I am not getting anything showing up in the asp-validation-summary.

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
```

I have also tried

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

Any ideas what I am missing.

Done loads of searching and cant see solution to my problem

Thanks

Comment: Could you please include the Model & Controller code

Comment: I'm having the same problem and none of the answers here look like they solve it (hence I guess why none are accepted and all have zero votes). Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: We need you to show the view, as well as the generated HTML for the form. Without those, we can only guess. My guess could be that you have some styling that puts `display: none !important;` on any element that has class `.validation-summary-errors`. This is a valid guess for example for why validation is working at field levels but not at the summary level LOL.

Comment: @DavidLiang There is no such styling on mine. Server side validation makes the asp-validation-summary render fine, it’s just not rendering for client side validation. If you have a working example of the validation summary rendering after client side validation please post it.

Comment: @zola25: sure here you go: https://github.com/davidliang2008/DL.NetCore.EmptySolution. I just checked in some codes just to show that: https://github.com/davidliang2008/DL.NetCore.EmptySolution/commit/989c101ea74a8712bbeee98d9fdf5030eb40d671

Comment: @DavidLiang Thanks for your effort, it works for the original question, as there is a validation summary displayed on submit. In my bounty I specified it needs to display on field change. So in this image https://ibb.co/JC4bQh6 I changed the fields but there is no validation summary displayed. I admit the question does not require after field change, it says nothing on this. I should ask a separate question, I will do this when I have time later today. If you'd like the bounty (not much for 11k :) ) you can post your code as an answer and I'll award it as it does answer the original question.

Comment: @zola25: I didn't do anything to get the validation summary displayed on submit. It was just a normal setup on a MVC application. I've tried to not load jquery-validation and jquery unobtrusive library, or just load one of them but not both and couldn't reproduce your issue so I wanted more information from you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the most recent MVC template from VS but the client side validation logic is likely in that 20000 line global.js file. They've obviously changed things a bit. The original question asker certainly doesn't have access to this, so your code is not an acceptable answer to their question anyway. But you've missed my main point - In the bounty I said I want the validation summary to show **when a field (input or select) is changed** (and obviously changed to an invalid state). Which your solution doesn't do unfortunately.

Comment: @zola25: I finally understand what's your problem is now. I have a simple solution for it: just copy `<span asp-validation-for=""></span>` and put them on top of the form. That way it shows the errors when a field is changed. Now you might want a more solid answer than this. If you could ask a separate question, I might be able to work on it and give you another answer. I don't think your problem is the same as this original asker had.

Comment: @David Liang Okay I've posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164533/display-asp-validation-summary-on-field-change). I understand your solution, I was looking for something that would really change the `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>`, but what you have is better than what I had before so it is definitely worth answering my question with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can include jquery script for validation tag-helper

```
<form asp-controller="home" asp-action="CreatePoll" method="post" class="mt-3">
        <div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name">Name of the Poll:</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>

    </form>

    @section scripts{

        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, field validation worked well, can display xx is required below the input window. But the `validation-summary` didn't show up.

At first, I have code below in my cshtml file,

```
<div class="row">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

and I had code below in my controller,

```
ModelState.AddModelError("key", "validation summary error");
return View(rdl);
```

then only `@Html.ValidationSummary()` worked, and `asp-validation-summary` didn't show up(if it displayed message, it should have black font)

[image]

Then I tried `asp-validation-summary="All"`, it worked. The [difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-validation-summary-tag-helper) between ALL and ModelOnly is ModelOnly will only display the invalid message for the model.

[image]

So I use `ModelState.AddModelError("", "validation summary error.");` in my Controller to make the `<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>` display  error message.

I only know it can make it display correctly, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

You should add this for each your model field with `asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"` and set `@Html.ValidationSummary()` before html form

```
//Validation Summary Parameters
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    bool excludePropertyErrors, // to include or exclude your field validation errors
    string message,
    object htmlAttributes,
    string headingTag
)

@Html.ValidationSummary() // use this with your desired parameters
<form>
  ...... // your inputs
  <input asp-for="YourField" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="YourField" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I have, and have set message to be * but want the text to display in the summary

Answer (score 0):

**Display field level error messages using ValidationSummary:**

By default, ValidationSummary filters out field level error messages. If you want to display field level error messages as a summary then specify excludePropertyErrors = false.

**Example: ValidationSummary to display field errors**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

So now, in the view will display error messages as a summary at the top. Please make sure that you don't have a ValidationMessageFor method for each of the fields.

official doc:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx

Hope it will be helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: This is the same as `<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>`...